# Writing to data files on the ClassPath does not reflect in Project?

Tags: java, classpath

My project structure is somewhat as follows:
    /src/main/java
       Main.java
    /src/main/resources
       data.txt

Now, in Main.java, I have something like:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new TestMain().getClass().getClassLoader();
String url = classLoader.getResource("data.txt").toString();
File file =new File(url.split(":")[1]);

//check if file exists, and reads current content:
System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());
System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(file)));

//Now write some more data to this file:
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file,true);
BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
bufferWritter.write("some more text");
bufferWritter.close();
```

Now the above runs OK... And, on each iteration, when we read the file, we can see that in fact, the extra text is being appended to the file.

However: when I look at the file in /src/main/resource I **cannot** see any changes. And more so, if I change/update this file, then all previous modifications are deleted.

My question therefore is: If I have a file that I want to store on classpath, such as data.txt, and in a way that I would want to do ongoing changes to the file, how I can organise my codebase to do this, and/or what changes do I need to make it in my code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you'll find that the data is actually changed in a `bin` directory (or wherever you've got the output set to).

I'd expect the build process to be compiling your source code and *copying* the resources to some other directory, and then running it from there. Rather than just printing out whether or not the file exists, print out the file itself, and I suspect you'll see that it's not in `src`.

Note that your current approach is fragile in that if the resource is in a jar file (for example) it *won't* be writable. Usually resources on the classpath are best considered read-only.

Comment: For storing I would use `File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.MyApp"); dir.mkdirs();`. And copy the resource data.txt initially there (as template).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. The file is actually being copied into a `build/` directory. So in this case, what is the correct way for having a file where running modifications can be made? (But in way that it can be accessed dynamically wherever the app is installed?)